# Pimcore bundle controller service subscriber

Tags: pimcore

Greetings fellow Pimcore devs, I'm working in on a project that runs on Pimcore X ! But I'm running agains some "inconveniences". When I try to reach my controller I get the error message:
`"App\Foo\Bar\Controller\SomeController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?`

let me show some code snippets:

`src\Foo\Bar\Controller\SomeController`

```php
namespace App\Foo\Bar\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/admin/Bar")
 */
class SomeController extends AdminController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/foo", name="foo-you-too")
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function someAction(): Response
    {
        die('howdy!');
    }
}
```

`src\Foo\Bar\DependencyInjection\BarBundleExtension`

```php
namespace App\Foo\Bar\DependencyInjection;

class BarBundleExtension extends ConfigurableExtension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadInternal(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

`src/Foo/Bar/Resources/config/services.yml`

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    #Foo\Bar\Controller\:
    #App\Bar\Controller\:
    App\Foo\Bar\Controller\:
        resource: '../../Controller'
        public: true
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

`src/Foo/Bar/Resources/config/pimcore/routing.yml`

```yaml
app:
  resource: "@Bar/Controller/"
  type:     annotation
```

`src/Foo/Bar/Resources/public/js/startup.js`

```js
pimcore.registerNS("pimcore.plugin.menusample");

pimcore.plugin.menusample = Class.create(pimcore.plugin.admin, {
    getClassName: function () {
        return "pimcore.plugin.menusample";
    },

    initialize: function () {
        pimcore.plugin.broker.registerPlugin(this);

        this.navEl = Ext.get('pimcore_menu_search').insertSibling('<li id="pimcore_menu_mds" class="pimcore_menu_item pimcore_menu_needs_children">Howdy there!</li>', 'after');
        this.menu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
            items: [{
                text: "Some text",
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_apply",
                handler: function (button) {
                    new Ext.Window({
                        title: t('-'),
                        width: '50%',
                        height: '80%',
                        layout: 'fit',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: "component",
                                autoEl: {
                                    tag: "iframe",
                                    src: "/admin/Bar/foo"
                                },
                                border: false
                            }
                        ]
                    }).show();
                }.bind(this)
            }],
            cls: "pimcore_navigation_flyout"
        });
        pimcore.layout.toolbar.prototype.mdsMenu = this.menu;
    },

    pimcoreReady: function (params, broker) {
        var toolbar = pimcore.globalmanager.get("layout_toolbar");
        this.navEl.on("mousedown", toolbar.showSubMenu.bind(toolbar.mdsMenu));
        pimcore.plugin.broker.fireEvent("mdsMenuReady", toolbar.mdsMenu);
    }
});

const menusamplePlugin = new pimcore.plugin.menusample();
```

I suspect there is something wrong with my services.yml, I already looked for similar StackOverflow questions but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the name of the DependencyInjection class name was wrong it should be the BarExtension and not BarBundleExtension like in the namespace.